# Showing Error- Except a parameter which is not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to execute the query but on the datastore parameter it is showing an error excepts a parameter which is not supplied.Please help me out regarding this.

My code is-

```
                           SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str);
                           conn.Open();
                           Console.WriteLine("TicketNo {0}", itm);

                           string SwimSR = "";
                           SwimSR += "Insert into SwimSR1(Id,State,Title,Datastore,AreaId,AreaPath,PlannedStartDate,PlannedEndDate,RequestedEta,SeManTexEta,Owner,Reason,ChangedBy,ChangedDate,CreatedBy,CreatedDate,NodeName,Trio,Type,BusinessCategory,Description)";
                           SwimSR += "Values(@Id,@State,@Title,@Datastore,@AreaId,@AreaPath,@PlannedStartDate,@PlannedEndDate,@RequestedEta,@SeManTexEta,@Owner,@Reason,@ChangedBy,@ChangedDate,@CreatedBy,@CreatedDate,@NodeName,@Trio,@Type,@BusinessCategory,@Description)";
                             SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SwimSR, conn);

                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id",swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.Id));

                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@State",swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.State));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Title",swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.Title));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Datastore",swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.Datastore));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AreaId", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.AreaId));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AreaPath", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.AreaPath));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PlannedStartDate", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.PlannedStartDate));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PlannedEnddate", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.PlannedEndDate));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RequestedEta", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.RequestedEta));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SemanTexEta", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.SeManTexEta));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Owner", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.Owner));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Reason", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.Reason));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChangedBy", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.ChangedBy));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChangedDate", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.ChangedDate));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CreatedBy", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.CreatedBy));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CreatedDate", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.CreatedDate));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NodeName", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.NodeName));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Trio", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.Trio));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Type", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.Type));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BusinessCategory", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.BusinessCategory));
                             cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Description", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.Description));


                           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                           Console.WriteLine("added");
                           conn.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Make the casing match:

```
... @SeManTexEta ...
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SemanTexEta", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.SeManTexEta));
```

Does that fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You used `@SeManTexEta` in your sql command but you declared in your parameter part as a `@SemanTexEta`.

As you can see, these are different.

Change your

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SemanTexEta", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.SeManTexEta));
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SeManTexEta", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.SeManTexEta));
```

Also [`SqlParameterCollection.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method has been deprecated. You can use [`SqlParameterCollection.AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead. Like;

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SeManTexEta", swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.SeManTexEta);
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting error near the Datastore..During Debugging also, I was facing the problem at that line only.

Comment: this is the error-The parameterized query '(@Id int,@State nvarchar(6),@Title nvarchar(57),@Datastore nvarc' expects the parameter '@Datastore', which was not supplied.

Comment: @user3011964 I think you get this error in store procedure or something? It is not relevant on this question I think..

Answer (score 0):

After reading above answers and comments ,
Please check your expected `datatype` for `Datastore` and datatype in your command parameter.

Also check if your cmd.parameter type is not `NULL` .

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Datastore",swimTicket[itm].swimTicketData.Datastore));
```